# Basic Function Query

Tags: function, parameter-passing

2 Questions regarding this piece of code. Code works but there is something I don't understand in the code regarding the is_win function.

Question 1 - When the function is_win is defined, is it called in the if statement, which is within the def play function?

Question 2 - If it is, I don't understand why it takes the parameters user and computer to perform the calculation as opposed to player and opponent. Normally when you call a function the information is converted  by the arguments that are defined in the function. But in this case, it seems to work the other way around. Can someone please explain why that is?

Thanks.

```
import random

def play():
    user = input ("What's your choice? 'R' for rock, 'P' for paper, 'S' for scissors: ")
    computer = random.choice(["r", "p", "s"])
    print (f"Computer chose {computer}")
    if user == computer:
        return ("You tie")

    if is_win(user,computer):
        return ("You won")

    return "You lost"

def is_win(player,opponent):
    if (player == "r" and opponent == "s") or (player == "s" and opponent == "p") or (player == "p" and opponent == "r"):
            return True

print (play())
```

Answer (score 0):

When the function `is_win(player, opponent)` is defined and called, `player` and `opponent` can be any variables and not necessarily have the same name.

Think of it this way, the following code:

```
if is_win(user, computer):
    return ("You won")
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if is_win(computer, user):
    return ("You lost")
```

In the first case, the user is the *player* and the computer is the *opponent*, while in the second example the computer is the *player* and the user is the *opponent*.

If you're have more confusion about this you need to read more about variables,  scopes and functions in python:

- https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html
- https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Functions.html#input-parameters

Comment: Where is the function is_win called in this code?

Comment: @JonSpelman: It's called at the first line of each of the code blocks.